# Why do people claim that Trantor is 130% larger than Earth in regards to surface area when it's less than half the size?

Tags: tv, foundation

I would like to know why people, websites, forums, etc. all claim that Trantor from *Foundation* is larger than Earth.

In the book, it's clearly stated that Trantor's surface area is 19,230,000,000 hectares.

Earth has a surface area of 51,001,000,000 hectares, so Trantor isn't even half its size.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please write a more civil question.  You should also cite the exact quote you're using as a reference.

Comment: FWIW, the 130% number simply falls out of a comparison of _land area_.  75M mile^2 is about 194M km^2; the land area of Earth is approximately 149M km^2, and 194/149 = 1.3 (130%).  We have no idea of either the total surface area of Trantor or the percentage covered by oceans, so there's no other useful comparison to draw.

Comment: @DavidW That actually seems like a straight-up answer to the question.  Considering how rudely the original was written, I assume it was meant to be rhetorical - but if an answer exists then an answer exists.  Voting to reopen.

Comment: The book does explicitly say it's talking about land area only: "All the land surface of Trantor, 75,000,000 square miles in extent, was a single city." Not sure why Rusty put it in hectares (and with extra digits that aren't actually correct if you translate 75 million square miles to hectares)--different edition or translation?

Comment: Attempted troll seemingly results in somewhat-useful clarification. Stack Exchange has life in it yet!

Comment: *sighs at missing the unedited "rude" question*

Comment: @DannyMcG - You can always have a nosey at the [timeline](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/256412/timeline) and [edit history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/256412/revisions)

Comment: @Valorum ....I see what people meant now, a bit condescending

Answer (score 11):

The fact cited in [the wiki](https://asimov.fandom.com/wiki/Trantor) is about the *land surface* of Trantor, not the overall surface area of the planet.  The relevant quotes from *Foundation* give us the *land* area:

> Its urbanization,  progressing steadily, had finally  reached the ultimate.  **All the land surface** of Trantor, 75,000,000 square  miles in extent, was a single city.  The population,  at its height,  was well in  excess of forty billions.
>
> <sub>*Foundation*, Chapter 3, ENCYCLOPEDIA GALACTICA</sub>

But Trantor is not all land; it has oceans as well:

> Trantor is tunneled over  a mile down. It's like an iceberg. Nine-tenths of
> it is out of sight. It even works itself out a few miles into **the sub-ocean
> soil at the shorelines.**
>
> <sub>*Foundation*, Chapter 3</sub>

Without knowing the fraction of Trantor's surface covered by oceans, we can only compare Trantor to Earth's *land area*, which is approximately 149 million km<sup>2</sup>.  (148 940 000 km<sup>2</sup> [per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth).)

The given 75 million square miles land area for Trantor is about 194 million km<sup>2</sup> (to the same amount of precision).  So the relative amount of land area is **194 / 149 = 1.30**, or **130%**, just as stated.  Note that this is *not* a comparison of the relative *sizes* of the planets, since we have no idea if Trantor is only 20% ocean, which would give it a total surface area less than half of Earth, or if it's 80% ocean, giving it nearly twice Earth's surface area.